# greek macros: teubner.sty's \og-macro doesn't work at all

Tags: incompatibility, greek

Before the latest update of teubner.sty (with GlyphNames) one could use the \og-macro (ὸ) as long as babel's french wasn't loaded (page 15 n. 1 of teubner-doc.pdf). Now, the \og-macro doesn't work at all: There is just nothing in the pdf-output where there was an \og in the .tex-file. In the .log-file it says

```
   ! Undefined control sequence.
     l.596   t\og{} kal\og n mhk\ea ti \og{}
```

There's nothing french in my .tex-file, and even when I remove each single package, TeXify, remove another package instead of the last one, the \og doesn't work. I can't see where it is redefined, not even savesymbol, which I used before and after different packages, helps.

MWS:

```
\pdfgentounicode=1
\input glyphtounicode
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\input{ix-utf8enc.dfu}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage[math=normal,greek,german,main=ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{gfsdidot,gfsporson}
\usepackage[GlyphNames,boldLipsian]{teubner}
\savesymbol{breve}
\savesymbol{og}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\restoresymbol{pplj}{breve}
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{DejaVuSansCondensed}
\Lipsiantrue
\ifFamily{pplj}{porson}
\usepackage[nonegthinspace,twothirds]{thinsp}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\,}{\thinspace\allowhyphens}
\newcommand{\hrsp}{\ifmmode\mskip1mu\else\kern0.08em\fi}
\ifFamily{pplj}{porson}
\addto\greek@shorthands{%
  \declare@shorthand{greek}{\/}{\textormath{\penalty\@M\discretionary{-}{}{\kern.03em}
 \allowhyphens}{}}
}
\Lipsiantrue
\ifFamily{pplj}{porson}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\subsection*{Platon \emph{Theaitetos} 184\hrsp b--185\hrsp d}
185\hrsp c\\
      \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}to\uc to o\usa\/te \osa yis      
      o\usa\/te \as ko\hg{} fa\ia netai, \as ll\aa{} ti \asa llo. \quad
      \textsc{JE.} T\ia{} d''\,o\us{} m\ea llei, \hra{} ge di\ag{} t\hc s
      gl\wa sshs d\ua namis? \quad \textsc{SW.} Kal\wc s l\ea geis. \hr{} 
      d\eg{} d\hg{} di\ag{} t\ia nos d\ua namis t\oa{} t''\,\es p\ig{} 
      p\ac si koin\og n ka\ig{} t\og{} \es p\ig{} to\ua tois
      dhlo\ic{} soi, \wrci{} t\og{} ((\esa stin)) \es p\/onom\aa zeis
      ka\ig{} t\og{} ((o\us k \esa sti)) ka\ig{} \arg{} nun\/d\hg{} 
      \hs rwt\wa men per\ig{} a\us t\wc n? to\ua tois p\ac si po\ic a 
      \as po\/d\wa seis \osa rgana di''\,\wrc n a\is sj\aa netai \hr m\wc n 
      t\og{} a\is sjan\oa menon \era kasta? \quad \textsc{JE.}  O\us s\ia an 
      l\ea geis ka\ig{} t\og{} m\hg{} e\isc nai, ka\ig{} \oR moi\oa\/thta 
      ka\ig{} \as n\/omoi\oa\/thta, ka\ig{} t\og{} ta\us t\oa n te ka\ig{} 
      t\og{} \era teron, \esa ti d\eg{} \era n te ka\ig{} t\og n \asa llon 
      \as rijm\og n per\ig{} a\us t\wc n.\\
      \og\og\og
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While the question is interesting, you should try and get a really minimal example.

Comment: You're right, I removed most useless packages and definitions. The rest I leave untouched as there _might_ be conflicts which I don't see. Nevertheless, I expect the problem to be in the teubner.sty itself -- though I wonder why teubner-doc.pdf mentions only the conflict with frenchb (which is: the quotation marks \og and \fg).

Comment: Then try removing everything else and if the error still occurs, post that code as your MWE. All posting that code says is that you expect other people to do that work for you. Of course anything might conflict. That's something you can check prior to posting though.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with 279 characters in 10 lines of code (and 1 of those is a blank line and 1 is only there so the output isn't empty and for comparison). \savesymbol is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[GlyphNames]{teubner}
\savesymbol{og}
\begin{document}
      \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}\og\end{otherlanguage}

      \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}to o\usa\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This avoids the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[GlyphNames]{teubner}
\savesymbol{og}
\restoresymbol{pplj}{og}
\begin{document}
      \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}\og\end{otherlanguage}

      \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}to o\usa\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

At least, assuming that is what \og is supposed to look like. I have no idea.

EDIT: Based on the OP's comments, I'm editing this answer. The above is correct for older versions of teubner. For newer versions the following shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[GlyphNames]{teubner}
\savesymbol{oG}
\begin{document}
      \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}\oG\end{otherlanguage}

      \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}to o\usa\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

and the following avoids the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[GlyphNames]{teubner}
\savesymbol{oG}
\restoresymbol{pplj}{oG}
\begin{document}
      \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}\oG\end{otherlanguage}

      \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}to o\usa\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

Note that it is not sufficient to update to use \oG. The \restoresymbol... is also needed in order for the character to display.

Output is as shown in the images above.

Comment: O  @cfr There must be a large bug in my computer (tlmgr and emacs), though I never changed anything in any file: Your most Minimal WE doesn't work on my computer neither, no matter which lines I move or add (in your MWE or in my not-so-M WE). No warning, no error in the log-file. Even without anything else than babel-greek and teubner \og doesn't show up, though in this six-line-case, without savesym.sty and savesymbol, I get the message '\og not defined'. That is: No \og (ὸ). With savesym.sty and savesymbol it just doesn't print, without savesym and savesymbol I get a warning 'not defined'.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann: Well the MWE is supposed to illustrate the problem so it isn't expected to produce the desired output. In the first picture I posted, the symbol doesn't display either. The second lot of code should display it correctly, though, as illustrated in the second picture I posted. When you typeset exactly that code, do you get different results? Note that the restoresymbol is crucial there.

Comment: O @cfr: Yes. Copy-pasting your code after 'This avoids the problem' and LaTeXing it (DIV and PDF) gives το οὔ and nothing more. No warnings, no complaints, nothing. Moving the different packages around, adding new ones ... doesn't change anything. The \og doesn't exist, though it is defined in teubner.sty.

Comment: That's puzzling. It works fine for me whether I latex to dvi or pdflatex to pdf. I even copied the code back from here and compiled that just to be certain. Which distribution of TeX do you use and which version do you have?

Comment: O @cfr (I have to write a letter before the @): The latest one. ubuntu 12.04, TeXLive 2013, updated yesterday, emacs 24.3, pdflatex: pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013), teubner.sty: 2013/12/13 v.4.1 (the problem started when I used the latest teubner-update).

Comment: o @cfr: The man or woman or hermaphrodite or whoever wrote the documentation, he, she or it shall henceforth be barred from human intercourse and no one will address him, she or it any further, nor man, nor woman, nor hermaphrodite. What is neither in README nor teubner-doc.pdf, I find not earlier than on page 45 of teubner.pdf: \og has changed to \oG. Nevertheless, teubner-doc speaks of \og and \og is even referred to on pages earlier than 45. This is no bad documentation, that's no documentation at all.

Comment: Why? Why would they change it to that, breaking backwards compatibility in such a weird way and not even telling people in neon letters? I guess the update really is very recent - my TeX Live is pretty current but apparently not quite enough to see this bug! (And, yes, it is a bug if they don't tell you it has changed and most of the documentation is inconsistent with reality.) I would file a bug against the documentation, at least.